# Mongodb aggregate to return result only if the lookup field has length

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections `users` and `profiles`. I am implementing a search with the following query:

```
User.aggregate(
      [
        { 
          $match: { 
          _id: { $ne: req.user.id },
          isDogSitter: { $eq: true },
          profileId: { $exists: true }
        }},
        {
          $project: {
            firstName: 1,
            lastName: 1,
            email: 1,
            isDogSitter: 1,
            profileId: 1,
        }},
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $project: {
                  __v: 0,
                  availableDays: 0,
              }},
              {
                $match: {
                  city: search
              }}
            ],
            as: "profileId",
        }}
      ],
      (error, result) => {
        console.log("RESULT ", result);
      }
    );
```

What this does is that its searches for the `city` in the `profiles` collection and when there is not search match then `profileId` becomes an empty array. What I really want is that if the `profileId` is an empty array then I don't want to return the other fields in the documents too. It should empty the array. Below is my current returned result.

```
RESULT  [
  {
    _id: 60cabe38e26d8b3e50a9db21,      
    isDogSitter: true,
    firstName: 'Test',
    lastName: 'Sitter',
    email: 'test@user.com',
    profileId: []
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$match` pipeline stage after the `$lookup` pipeline stage and
add the empty array condition check over there.

```
User.aggregate(
      [
        { 
          $match: { 
          _id: { $ne: req.user.id },
          isDogSitter: { $eq: true },
          profileId: { $exists: true }
        }},
        {
          $project: {
            firstName: 1,
            lastName: 1,
            email: 1,
            isDogSitter: 1,
            profileId: 1,
        }},
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $project: {
                  __v: 0,
                  availableDays: 0,
              }},
              {
                $match: {
                  city: search
              }}
            ],
            as: "profileId",
        }}
        {
          $match: {  // <-- Newly added $match condition
            "profileId": {"$ne": []}
          },
        },
      ],
      (error, result) => {
        console.log("RESULT ", result);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know, we can use `$match` for multiple times. Currently, I am looking at all the documents to find the search result, do you know if I only want to attach one document to the user collection and search on that document only. I have `profileId` field in user collection who has a reference to documents of `profiles` collection.

Comment: @GurkiranSingh You can use any pipeline stage and multiple times as you want. Coming to the embedding part, It's better to embed all `profiles` documents to `user` collection if 1. The relation between them is one-to-many, 2. The number of profiles for a user will not be more than 100, 3. The user-to-profile lookup operation will be performed on a regular basis. This is subjective and depends entirely on the application that you are building, so it's hard for me to suggest a methodology without your application knowledge. Hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am looking at `$lookup` documentation, we can do one to one relation between the `profiles` and `users` using the `localField` and `foreignField` approach, but then it doesn't let you to use pipeline on it, like for my case `$match`. For my application, one particular user document has only one particular profile document. Can you please suggest any  approach on this ?

Comment: If the user and profile are a one-to-one relation, then it's better to embed the `profile` data as a sub-document in the `user` collection. It will save you a lot of time (since the `$lookup` operation is expensive) and your data and application will be less complex to work on. P.S. you can perform additional operations on `$lookup` using `let` and `pipeline` options instead of `localField` `foreignField` approach.